# How do people working on the Busy Beaver function keep track of all the turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem, busy-beaver

I'm a CS undergrad so forgive me if this question isn't formulated well. I got curious about the Busy Beaver function recently, and it got me wondering how all the n-state Turing machines are kept track of.

Is there like a list of all of the machines, along with whether they halt or not? Or is there some other way?

Comment: I think wikipedia has the (short) list of all *known* busy beavers. And the highest number of states there is, unsurprisingly, low.

Comment: @rus9384 but that is not my question. The Busy Beaver is the machine that achieves the maximum number of ones. But what I want to know is how do you keep track of all the n-state TMs so that you could evaluate which ones halt (and don't).

Comment: I suppose they prove which machines do not halt and show for how long the rest of machines run. Which is in general impossible, but if a machine has too few states to encode the halting problem in it, it is possible.

Comment: @rus9384 okay but how do you deal with trillions of TMs, like when n=4?